# html file input only select one file

Tags: html

I want that the **input file** accept only one file.

I mean when I try select file for upload only one file can be select

I know that we can use multiple
like this

```html
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

but can we use something like this?

```html
<input type="file" name="img" multiple = false>
```

This is my code:

```html
<form action="/Panel/Uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/inrsaurabh/pen/XGmPJY) link.

Don't use `multiple` attribute.

```
<input type="file" name="img">
```

We can see that we can't select more than one file.

Tested on Mozilla and chrome.

> You can even restrict using js

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").on('click', () => {
        var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>1){
         // handle here 
           return false;
        }
    });    
});
```

In Js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const submitButton = document.querySelector("input[type='submit']");
  submitButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const fileUpload = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");
    if (parseInt(fileUpload.files.length) > 1) {
      // Handle here
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't like this:

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple = false>
```

But if you wan't only to select one file you can do something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="img">
```

You just have to remove "multiple".

Comment: i remove it but still can select more than one file just update the Q